# how to fix error Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined from readline function

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdin

I want to use the readline function to get input. But when using this function, this error is displayed. What is the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgRNT.png)

```
const readline = require("readline").createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

readline.question(`What's your name?`, (name) => {
  console.log(`Hi ${name}!`);
  readline.close();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `require` function is only native available on [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules-commonjs-modules), it's not used on browser contexts.
So, in order to use the readline module, you need to run your script in a [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) environment.